# My friend is invited to my private server in Roblox, and it says She needs Download Roblox on Computer even though she plays on Mobile

Tags: roblox

So, I invited 2 friends to join a VIP Server in Roblox but one can't join. It says that they need to download Roblox but the directions are for computer even though she plays on Mobile/IOS. She doesn't have any other devices to play on, and we've been searching for answers but can't find any. Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

Does she already have the app installed? If she is just on the website, it will not work correctly. She needs to have the app installed and use that instead of the website.

Answer (score 1):

She's on Android/iOS. She must search Roblox from the App Store of the device, install it, and launch it from there and she will be able to join.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reinstall ROBLOX, or check for updates. Or it could be that you are on the website.